# WooCommerce Webhooks not firing because of error in wp-includes/meta.php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to implement a WooCommerce Webhook that fires when an order was updated to tell another system that it needs to generate a file based on the payload provided via the webhook. For getting to know what is actually sent and in which cases I've created a new WebHook that is sending to a RequestBin:

**Webhook Configuration**

```
Status: Active
Topic: Order updated
Delivery URL: a RequestBin URL
Secret: somesecret
API version: WP Rest API Integration v3
```

I've noticed that nothing was sent and WordPress was logging the error shown below:

**error message in debug.log**

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in .../woocommerce/wp-includes/meta.php on line 582
```

**wp-includes/meta.php**

```php
580 if ( ! $meta_cache ) {
581     $meta_cache = update_meta_cache( $meta_type, array( $object_id ) );
582     $meta_cache = $meta_cache[ $object_id ];
583 }
```

I've nailed down the issue further and it has shown that `update_meta_cache()` in line 581 is sometimes returning `false` and, as a result, `$meta_cache` is not an array but a boolean. This case can happen only if `$object_ids` or `$meta_type` is empty/null or `_get_meta_table()` inside `update_meta_cache()` returns null. Unfortunately, a webhooks-delivery log file is not created by WooCommerce.

Am I doing something wrong, is proper error handling missing in line 582 or is it just a configuration issue or bug?

Thanks in advance.